# How to display View into a specific Zone/Shape in Orchard

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, themes, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

In my module, I created a route, controller and view for the action.

When I visit the page, all I get is the contents of the view. Is there a way to display that specific view into a zone in the template/theme? Or if possible, a specific shape?

Comment: If you must cross-post, please provide a link to the other one.

Comment: It's been answered here: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/454481